# Angular increase scope value based on values in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to increase the amount of a value in $scope by using values in an ng-repeat. I would like to know if this is possible.

I have the following

```
<div ng-repeat="field in selected.inhoud.fields">
  <p>Veldnaam: {{field.title}}</p>
  <p>Grootte in %:
    <input type="range" min="10" max="80" ng-model="field.width" ngvalue="field.width" />
  </p>
</div>
```

I want to get the total width of all the field.width.

Thanks

Comment: explain in more detail , if each width was 10, the second input should actually show 20? Third input would be 30 etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a function pass a parameter (iun this example$index) and do any calculation you need.

```
<div ng-repeat="field in selected.inhoud.fields">
        <p>Veldnaam: {{field.title}}</p>
        <p>Grootte in %: {{ calculateValue($index) }}
           <input type="range" min="10" max="80" ng-model="field.width" ngvalue="field.width"/>
        </p>
    </div>

var app = angular.module('angularjs-app', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.data.calculateValue = function(index){
     console.log('some value:'+index*.1);
     $scope.increment += index; 
  }; 

  console.log($scope.increment);
});
```